# ASPX - Storing MysqlConnection in Session

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm just wondering has anybody tried this.  It seems so crazy that I need to open a mysql Connection for every call to the database.  Sometimes a page requires 3 of 4 calls to the database and it takes extra time to open the connection.

if I create a new Session class and {get;set}; my connection in that class.  Is there any harm in this?  Theoretically I would this that performance would be increased.  Has anybody tried it?  And is there any big setbacks?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why in session and not in config??

Comment: @Ankit  Well because the connection would remain open, and I dont have to keep reopening it.  I can also add the users name to the connection string.  And in anon/forms auth i can see the user connected

Answer (score 0):

The MySql Connector/Net supports connection pooling and this is enabled by [default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html).

Typically, you want to close your connection as soon as possible to avoid using up the pool, so storing the connected MySqlConnection in the session would be a bad idea.

Comment: Mufaka - Know about pooling, but if I do it via session I can add security based on the userid and then add that userid to the connection string.  I can even see what commands are being run under forms auth

Comment: It's a matter of scale. If you keep an active connection for each session, you will be using way more resources than required. Calling open on a connection that is pooled isn't that expensive because the network connection has already been made.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the session without closing on every call by setting it up in the global.asax Session_start Method then closing it in the Sessions_Stop method.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** store a `MySqlConnection` in a session. It simply isn't possible. The class isn't even serializable so if you used out-of-proc sessions your application would probably explode with an exception.

You **can** store a reference to a connection in the application domain by using a global class or Global.asax but with pooling this is needless anyhow, you should allow pooling to manage your connections.

Comment: Lloyd - Why Cant i create a session of a global class?

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure I understand?